# Test http2 in Azure api management and Azure app service backend

Tags: azure, http2, azure-api-management, azure-appservice

I have an Azure API Management and Azure app services as its backend. I have enabled http2 in both APIM and app services. But when I test the APIs from Azure portal, it takes http/1.1. How to force it to use http/2?

Answer (score 0):

I tested to enable http2 in azure APIM, it's true that there's no configuration to use http2.

And what I wanna say is that if someone need to make sure the policy of enabling http2 take effect, [this website](https://myssl.com/http2_check.html?domain=huryapim.azure-api.net&port=443) will help.